# rails integration testing issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

I'm trying to do some integration testing using Rails own testing system, on the user model as appears in the rails tutorial.

In routes.rb I did the following mapping:

```
match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
```

The test looks like that:

```
class UserStoriesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "sign up" do
    User.delete_all
    post_via_redirect "/users",  
           user: {name: 'david', 
                  email: 'david@example.com', 
                  password: 'qwe123', 
                  password_confirmation: 'qwe123'}
    assert_response :success
    users = User.all
    assert_equal 1, users.size, users.size   
  end
end
```

No matter what I do I can't make it create a new record so the second assert is failed. 
I also tried failing it on purpose by setting wrong confirmation password, and it didn't fail on the first assert.
I tried only post instead of post_via_redirect, or using "signup" path instead of "/users", with no change.

I'm surely doing something stupid. What do I miss here?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your not actually filling out the sign up form. It looks like your using test::unit, what you need it webrat or capybara to handle request specs, I recommend the latter.

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

https://github.com/brynary/webrat

Answer (score 0):

This response is likely too old to be of much use to you, but a couple things stand out to me.

1) This shouldn't be an integration test, as you are not testing the interaction between multiple controllers. This should be a functional test, which is used for testing individual controllers, in this case, your UsersController. This is important as different methods and functions are avalible/loaded depending on your declaration.

```
class UserStoriesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
```

Will give you a very different environment than

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
```

Note that the integration test is part of ActionDispatch while the functional test is a part of ActiveSupport. I highly suggest moving this to a functional test, and this is likely the source of your errors.

2) Using delete_all is a bit extreme. You can actually just do an assert test when you do your post to see if there is a difference in count.

```
assert_difference('User.count') do
  post :create, :user => {name: 'david', 
              email: 'david@example.com', 
              password: 'qwe123', 
              password_confirmation: 'qwe123'}
end
```

This will assert that the User.count is different from before you run what is in the do loop and once it ends. That block there can replace everything you have in your "sign up" test. For a fun one, you can change assert_difference to assert_no_difference, and if that passes, you know something is wrong with your post method in your users_controller.rb (this is where I assume your problem actually lies).

3) Your assert_equal line looks a bit odd. The last argument passed is the message it will spit out on failure. Printing out just a number might work for one test, but will look very strange over many tests. Something such as the following I believe is closer to norms:

```
assert_equal 1, User.count, "Expected User.count to be equal to 1, instead it is equal to: " + User.count.to_s
```

Also note that you can just use ModelName.count instead of doing something like putting all of the records into an object and then calling the size of that object. That can get very messy, very quickly.

Finally, as a general debugging tool, you can throw puts statements, or logger statements all over the place to see what is actually going on.

```
puts User.count
```

After your delete_all and your post_via_redirect would tell you very quickly what is going wrong where. if you use the logger method, it will be written to the log in your appname/log/ENV.log. So if you are running tests, it will be in test.log.

```
logger.debug User.count
```

Your logs will also keep records of all of the requests, so you can read and see if you are getting 200 OKs, 302 Redirects, etc.

I suggest checking out the following guides provided by rails, they are great starting places:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Hope this helps someone!